# Combine sortable html table (sortable.html.table) with interactive scatter plot (rbokeh) in R

Tags: html, r, scatter-plot

I am creating R output using the SortableHTMLTables package to create a sortable data table as well as the rbokeh package to create an interactive scatter plot.  I can successfully get both on separate pages.  I would like to combine these onto one single page (so that the plot is seen first, and the data table is seen below.  See the existing R code below:

```
library(SortableHTMLTables)
library(rbokeh)

DATASET=data.frame(x=1:5,y=6:2,z=6:10)

# Use rbokeh to create interactive plot
g<-figure(width = NULL, height = NULL) %>%
 ly_points(x, y, data = DATASET, color="black", hover = z) 
# Output rbokeh file to html output
rbokeh2html(g, file = "c:/r_samples/plot.html")

# Output the sortable html table.
sortable.html.table(DATASET,"table.html","c:/r_samples/")
```